# Element not part of the graph when using VGG for data generation and loss calculation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I have a VGG19 encoder which takes an input image `y` of `(256,256,3)` and returns a tensor of dimension `(32,32, 512)` from conv-4-1 layer of vgg. I need to turn it into a numpy array to apply some transformations and reconstruct the image using my decoder.

In short, I'm trying to train the decoder network like so:

```
x = vgg_encoder(y)  # generate features from image y
x = do_extra_transformation(x) # for example, reshape and apply K means to shift features towards their cluster centres
y_pred = decoder(x) # try to reconstruct the image y from features
loss = calculate_loss(y, y_pred) # calculate reconstruction loss using VGG loss
```

However, when I run the code, I get the error:
`ValueError: Tensor Tensor("block4_conv1/Relu:0", shape=(?, 32, 32, 512), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.`

I'm assuming the error comes from tensorflow diconnecting the graph after I call predict on VGG to generate features. I don't see why this is a problem, since it technically only used for data generation, and isn't part of the computation graph for training!

---

#### Full code, you can run with `python example.py` below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

class CustomModel:

    def __init__(self, im_h, im_w, im_c):
        self.im_shape = (im_h, im_w, im_c)
        self.vgg_features_shape = (None, None, 512)
        self.vgg_loss_model = self.build_vgg_loss()
        self.kernel_size = (3,3)
        self.decoder = self.build_decoder()


    def build_vgg_loss(self):
        vgg = VGG19(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=self.im_shape)
        vgg.outputs = vgg.get_layer('block4_conv1').output
        model = Model(inputs=vgg.inputs, outputs=vgg.outputs)
        model.trainable = False

        return model

    def build_decoder(self):
        """
        Mirrors the VGG network with max-pooling layers replaces by UpScaling Layers
        """

        i = Input((None, None, 512))
        x = Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same')(i)

        x = UpSampling2D()(x)
        for _ in range(4):
            x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same')(x)

        x = UpSampling2D()(x)
        for _ in range(2):
            x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same')(x)

        x = UpSampling2D()(x)
        for _ in range(2):
            x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same')(x)

        x = Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same')(x)

        model = Model(inputs=i, outputs=x)

        return model


    def get_loss(self, y_pred, y):

        vgg_model = self.vgg_loss_model

        def content_loss(y_pred, y):

            dif = vgg_model(y) - vgg_model(y_pred)
            sq = K.square(dif)
            s = K.sum(sq, axis=-1)
            sqrt = K.sqrt(s)
            loss = K.sum(sqrt)

            return loss

        return content_loss(y_pred, y)


class DataLoader:

    def __init__(self, vgg):
        self.vgg = vgg

    def gen(self):
        while True:
            y = np.random.randn(256, 256,3)
            x = self.vgg.predict(np.expand_dims(y, 0)).reshape((32,32,512)) # if this is turned into a np.array, everything works as expected
            yield x, np.random.randn(256, 256,3) 


model = CustomModel(256,256,3)

# dl = DataLoader(datapath='./trainer/data/', mst=mst)

output_types=(
    tf.float32,
    tf.float32
 )
output_shapes=(
    tf.TensorShape([None, None, None]),
    tf.TensorShape([None, None, None])
)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(DataLoader(model.vgg_loss_model).gen,
                                   output_types=output_types, 
                                   output_shapes=output_shapes)

ds = ds.repeat().batch(1)
iterator = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
x, y = iterator.get_next()
y_pred = model.decoder(x)


loss = model.get_loss(y_pred, y)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01)
train_opt = opt.minimize(loss)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init_op)
    opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    for i in range(5):
        sess.run(train_opt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the input of the task you described is an image and the output is also the same image. Therefore, the model you construct must contains all the parts i.e. **encoder** + **decoder**. Of course, you can choose to not train any of them (as you have chosen to not train the encoder). So here are the changes you need to apply:

The following is wrong, because `y` and `y_pred` is the true and predicted outputs of **decoder**, so it does not make sense to apply the `vgg_model` (i.e. encoder) on them:

```
dif = vgg_model(y) - vgg_model(y_pred)
```

You just want to compare the reconstructed image with the original image. So just change it to this:

```
dif = y - y_pred
```

(Further, you don't need that `vgg_model = self.vgg_loss_model` in `get_loss` anymore; actually, `get_loss` could be defined as a static method of `CustomModel` class, without that inner `custom_loss` function).

---

```
def gen(self):
    while True:
        y = np.random.randn(256, 256,3)
        x = self.vgg.predict(np.expand_dims(y, 0)).reshape((32,32,512))
        yield x, np.random.randn(256, 256,3)
```

As we mentioned, the input and output pf the model are the same thing (further, by using `self.vgg.predict` you are effectively removing the **encoder** from the whole model computation graph). Just change it to this:

```
def gen(self):
    while True:
        x = np.random.randn(256, 256,3)
        yield x, x  # same input and output
```

---

And finally this line:

```
y_pred = model.decoder(x)
```

First apply the encoder, then apply decoder on the output of encder to reconstruct the image. So implement what you say:

```
y_pred = model.decoder(model.vgg_loss_model(x))
```

---

Final note: I think in these situations drawing a big-picture diagram of the whole computation graph on a piece of paper, ideally before starting the implementation, would really help to understand the problem better and save a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Thanks, actually, I'm not able to change the loss function as I'm trying to implement the Feature Reconstruction Loss function (which uses VGG) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.08155.pdf . If I had to draw out, first, I have an image `y` that I input into the encoder, to get VGG features (They need to be numpy arrays as I'm doing some extra transformations with them once I have them). Then these features are input into the decoder to reconstruct the image with the VGG reconstruction loss. I tried to provide a complete reproducible example of what's required.

Comment: In essense, I need to split the training into 2 parts: One part which uses VGG to create my training data (I wanted to make this a separate graph), and the second part is the normal training where I have a Decoder and VGG loss

Comment: @GRS Note that to compute the loss you need the original image. Now if you remove the VGG model from computation graph (by using `predict`) then the computation graph would be disconnected and therefore the loss could not be computed. If you want to do some extra transformations, then do it using the TF operations or Keras backend operations, and not the numpy. In other words you need Tensor operations, not numpy array ops.

Comment: That's the problem... I need to apply K means to the vgg features to squeeze them closer towards their centres, before putting them back into the decoder. One hacky way is to run data generation first and write tf records, and then  create a new script to read these tf records and train the decoder. I just hoped to find a solution that can do all elegantly at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can check a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178638/7454706

Create one extra function

```
def load_model():
    global model
    model = yourmodel(weights=xx111122)
        # this is key : save the graph after loading the model
    global graph
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

Then before predicting:

```
with graph.as_default():
   preds = model.predict(image)
   #... etc
```

There is a discussion on this issue : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14356
I think it is an issue with `ops.py` at:

```
   3034     with self._lock:
-> 3035       return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
   3036
```

If you can provide error for the whole code, it would be more easier to resolve.